# How to validate an input in Angular 2

Tags: angular, validation, input

I have an input place and I want this input to have length from 3 to 7 and not allow special characters.

```
<input  required maxlength="7" minlength="3" class="plate"  type="text"  #a>
```

I tried this but I want to print a message just when I leave the input place whithout having filling it properly

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: `ng-model` is not valid Angular syntax. Are you sure you're looking at the right documentation?

Comment: @Anna what do you mean with "not allow special characters." ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the pattern attribute with an appropriate regex pattern, like this:

> pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,7}"

Full input example:

> ```
> <input required class="plate" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,7}" #a>
> ```

To validate the input:

for simplicity, you can use input:invalid CSS selector:

> ```
> <input required class="plate" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,7}" #a>
> <span class="validation-msg">Not Valid</span>
>
> .validation-msg {
>     display: inline-block;
> }
> input:invalid {
>     color: red;
> }
>
> input:invalid ~ .validation-msg {
>     display: inline-block;
>   }
> ```

or for something powerful use template form.
https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: Thank you very mutch. I want also don;t let me leave the box if I put something like "@#%FFfjkhvjfhjdhgkjsdhk" that doesn't match with the restrictions and print an error message